# Threading: Variable Access and Termination of a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, global-variables, sharpdevelop

Let me start by showing you my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class MathQuiz
{
  static void Main() 
  {
   int score = 0;
   string preanswer;
   decimal answer = 0;
   Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Project5, a MathQuiz project.");
   Console.WriteLine("You will be asked 10 questions, and will have 30 seconds to read and answer each one.");
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to begin.");
   Console.ReadKey(true);
   Console.WriteLine("What is 2 + 2?");
    Thread ask = new Thread (new ThreadStart (MathQuiz.prompt));
    ask.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    //This is where I want to end the thread if it isn't already done.
    if (answer == 4)
    {
     score = score+1; //Here's where I don't know if my adding is correct.
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to move on to the next question!");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
  }

  static void prompt()
  {
   preanswer = (Console.ReadLine());
   if (!decimal.TryParse(preanswer, out answer))
  {
   Console.WriteLine("That wasn't even a number or decimal!");
  }
   else
       {
     answer = decimal.Parse(preanswer);
     }
  }
}
```

So, when I try and compile this code, I get CS0103 errors for preanswer and answer in the "prompt" method.

This leads to 3 questions:

- What EXACTLY do I have to do to make preanswer and answer accessible to the "prompt" method?
- Did I add 1 onto the score variable correctly?
- How can I terminate a thread if it is running? (In this case, the "ask" thread wouldn't end until they typed an answer.)

Please just tell me what to change. I don't know coding words and terminology because I just started a few weeks ago. Please try to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      static string preanswer;
      static decimal answer = 0;

      static void Main() 
      {
       int score = 0;
       //string preanswer;
       //decimal answer = 0;
...
```

etc.

Comment: Wait- do you want me to establish the variables outside of the methods? I didn't even know that was possible...

Comment: Ah, it worked! Do you know anything about terminating the "ask" thread?

Comment: Console.ReadLine would have to return (fail) - I don't know any way of doing that other than to press Ctrl-Break, which I believe would terminate the main thread as well, but you would never do this (use a separate thread for user input) in a real-world app anyway. Most things that a thread normally waits on have ways to force them to wake up when you need to terminate a thread.

Comment: Perhaps I'll put up a new question to be more specific, because the time issue has grown a bit. It has multiple flaws the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the thread, use Join()... This will tell the thread which the function is called on to wait for the thread until it joins back:

```
ask.Join(int);
```

Comment: No, I want to have the "ask" thread have a time limit. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: OH, I see. What if the user answers before the time limit is up? Will this be overridden?

Comment: Scratch that, it does. Thanks so much!